# C Binary & Linear Search

Tags: c, time-complexity, binary-search, linear-search

Hello i want to draw the time/array size graph for binary and linear search algorithms.(Worst, best and average case for array size = 1 000, 10 000,100 000,1 000 000). I'm using DEV C++. However, when i run the code for array size = 1 000 000, the program crashes. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
   if (r >= l)
   {
        int mid = l + (r - l)/2;

        if (arr[mid] == x)  return mid;

        if (arr[mid] > x) return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
   }

   return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
   int arr[10] = {2,5,8,9,15,18,19,25,34,50};
   int n = sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);
   int x = 10;
   int result = binarySearch(arr, 0, n-1, x);
   (result == -1)? printf("Element is not present in array")
                 : printf("Element is present at index %d", result);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using dynamically allocated arrays instead of statically allocated ones.

Comment: What does it tell you when it crashes?

Comment: You can use smaller data types than INT perhaps...Try SHORT

Comment: If `x` is not in the array, your `binarySearch()` will be infinitely recursive, since the only way the function returns without a doing recursive call is if `arr[mid] == x`.  The value`10` is not in the array, hence the crash.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating array `arr` on stack. For 1 000 000 elements you need 4 MB of memory (assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`). On Windows for example most of cases stack has default limit of 1 MB. For quick fix define `arr` as `static`

```
static int arr[size];
```

or put in global scope outside function body or as others said, use dynamic allocation.

Comment: He could use the heap instead, as you suggested in your Edit :)